# Return a value from a dictionary alphabetically

Tags: python, dictionary

How would I get the some value, alphabetically, from a dictionary in python?

For example, if we have:

```
dict = {'A':1, 'B':7, 'C':3}
```

How would I get it to return the highest value in the alphabet from the dictionary (1), the second highest (7) and the lowest (3)?

Comment: If those are what you want, a dictionary may not be the best structure to store your data in.  Consider instead an iterable structure such as a list of tuples ```[("A", 1), ...]```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/613183/python-sort-a-dictionary-by-value

Answer (score 3):

The pure-Python [sortedcontainers module](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/) has a [SortedDict](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/sorteddict.html) type that can help you. It maintains the dict keys automatically in sorted order and is well documented and tested. You use it just as you would a dict:

```
>>> from sortedcontainers import SortedDict
>>> d = SortedDict({'A': 1, 'B': 7, 'C': 3})
>>> list(d.keys())
['A', 'B', 'C']
```

Iterating keys will be much faster this way if you do a lot of edits than constantly re-sorting the keys manually. The sorted containers module is very fast and has a [performance comparison](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html) page with benchmarks against alternative implementations.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the keys, then get the value based on the index

```
>>> def get_alphabetically(my_dict, indx):
       key = list(sorted(my_dict))[indx]
       return my_dict[key]
>>> get_alphabetically({'A':1, 'B':7, 'C':3}, 0) # "Highest" value in alphabet
1
>>> get_alphabetically({'A':1, 'B':7, 'C':3}, -1) # "Lowest" value in alphabet
3
>>> get_alphabetically({'A':1, 'B':7, 'C':3}, 1) # "Second highest" value in alphabet
7
```

Having said this, you may have an XY problem, where you are not using the appropriate data structure for your problem.

Comment: But, of course this gives an O(nlogn) solution.  Ideally, you should be able to do something like this in O(logn) operations I would think.

Comment: @mgilson I guess, but do we know the size of the dictionary?  If it's not large, is that an issue?  Anyway, I think the correct answer would not be to use this function, but to rethink the data structure in the first place.

Comment: Yes, a new datastructure is what I'm proposing.  I'm not saying that this answer is _wrong_.  Given OP's constraint that you're using a `dict`, this is about as good as you _can_ do.

Answer (score 0):

```
sorted(my_dict.items(),reverse=True,key=lambda x:x[1])
```

I think would essentially do what you want ...